# Applying an IF STATEMENT to my word generator

Tags: objective-c, if-statement, conditional-statements

When I try adding an "if" statement to my word generator I get an error stating "Expected Expression". If I take the if statement out, it works fine but what I want to do is have several word generators and depending on the value of my variable "variable" determine which word generator is accessed.

Example: If "variable" is equal to 1 then the first word generator is accessed. If "variable is equal to 2 then the second word generator is accessed

Below is the code from my implementation file.

```
#import "ViewController2.h"
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "ViewController3.h"


@interface ViewController2 ()
@end

@implementation ViewController2
-(IBAction)random {
    if (int variable = 3) {
        int text = rand() %3;
        switch (text) {
            case 0:
                introLabel.text = @"Test 1";
                break;
            case 1:
                introLabel.text = @"Test 2";
                break;
            case 2:
                introLabel.text = @"Test 3";
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
-(IBAction)backButton:(id)sender {
    ViewController *viewController2 = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil     bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:viewController2 animated:YES];
}

-(IBAction)moreButton:(id)sender {
    ViewController3 *viewController2 = [[ViewController3 alloc] initWithNibName:nil     bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:viewController2 animated:YES];
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: isn't variable always equals to 3 in your case?

Comment: I bet it doesn't say "expand expression" but "expected expression". Don't you find it a bit weird that I know better the error message without having read it than you *supposedly* (but not actually) having read it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is unclear but I think you are talking about the line:

```
if (int variable = 3) {
```

That is invalid Objective-C syntax. Perhaps you want:

```
if (variable == 3) {
```

This assumes you have an instance variable named `variable` (which is a terrible name).

So your `random` method becomes something like:

```
-(IBAction)random {
    if (variable == 1) {
        int text = rand() %3;
        switch (text) {
            case 0:
                introLabel.text = @"Test 1";
                break;
            case 1:
                introLabel.text = @"Test 2";
                break;
            case 2:
                introLabel.text = @"Test 3";
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    } else if (variable == 2) {
        // process the 2nd word generator here
    } else if (variable == 3) {
        // process the 3rd word generator here
    }
}
```

Again, you need to add an instance variable named `variable` and you set that value somewhere appropriate. Or `variable` can be another local variable assigned the value of `rand()` like you do with the `text` variable.

Comment: I know "variable" is a bad name, it was more for example purposes because I am trying to figure out what method I will use. 

To clarify your response, you say "you need to add an instance variable name "variable" and you set that value somewhere appropriate". Where exactly would that be? I am new to objective c and this is the first time I tried coding in about 9 or 10 years so Im a little rusty. 

Also, if I understand your answer correctly, when I create the else if statements for my remaining random text values...it will still be triggered by the same button?

Comment: I think I got it to work. I declared my variable in my header file    "int variable;"    I just need to know how to apply a value to the variable and I should be moving in the right direction. Where would I add a value to the variable? Would I do this after the "@implementation" in my .m file?